# different uses of Call in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I was assigned to understand the code that was written by some other person so far I could understood to some extent but one line is causing me trouble

```
call set mmm=%%mon:~%id%,3%%
```

To the extent I understand `call` is used to initiate another `batch` file but in the above line there was variable set to some value but I am not sure what does that line does.

Also how does `%%` is used here as far as I know `%` is used to retrive the value from a variable.

Complete code is here:

```
set mon=JANFEB
set id=123
call set mmm=%%mon:~%id%,3%%
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a two-stage substitution, allowing you to use *variables* within the interpretation. Normally, with an expression like:

```
%str:~start,len%
```

the `start` and `len` must be numeric constants rather than variables. So this is the way you use a variable instead of a constant.

Starting with:

```
set mmm=%%mon:~%id%,3%%
```

In the first stage, `%%` markers are replaced with `%` and `%id%` is replaced with `123`, giving:

```
set mmm=%mon:~123,3%
```

In the second stage, it's interpreted as you would expect, although the offset `123` seems a little strange in this case.

You can see the effect here:

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off

rem               1         2         3         4
rem     01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456
set mon=JAN.FEB.MAR.APR.MAY.JUN.JUL.AUG.SEP.OCT.NOV.DEC
rem                                 ^
rem                                28

set id=28
call set mmm=%%mon:~%id%,3%%
echo %mmm%

endlocal
```

which outputs `AUG`.

Comment: Thanks for your response.. if `%%` is interpreted as `%` then what is the purpose of using `%%` instead we can only use `%`. How does `Call` work here?

Comment: @Siva, `call` introduces the second stage. The reason you need `%%` is because that becomes `%` during the first stage.

Answer (score 1):

Two steps:

first, the value of `id` is substituted into the expression, so it becomes `set mmm=%%mon:~123,3%%`

Then the expression is evaluated - as a single-line "subroutine", removing one level of `%` : `set mmm=%mon:~123,3%`

so, attempts to set `mmm` to the 3 characters following the 1323rd character in `mon` (counting from "character 0")

Which should "set" `mon` to *nothing*

(if `id` was `3`, then `mmm` would be set to `Feb`)